# I have a certain issue moving files with Python

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I wrote a script with Python which allows me to move files according their extension, to another folder , if it is a Music file then the file goes to the Music folder and so on. The thing is that I have to run the program inside the directory even though i coded it to run in the folders I type in, for the program to work properly, if i'm outside the folder it tells me that the file already exist in the folder which is going to be moved, which is not true, so i have to place myself in the folder and run the script for it to work as it was programmed. I'm kinda new here, I was looking if I can find a solution but I couldn't find it, if anyone can help me, I would appreciate it. Here is the code:

```
import os
import shutil

docs = [
    ".doc",
    ".docx",
    ".odt",
    ".pdf",
    ".rtf",
    ".txt",
    ".wpd",
    ".xls",
    ".xlsx",
    ".xml",
    ".ppt",
    ".pptx",
    ".pps",
    ".ppsx",
    ".odp",
    ".csv",
    ".py",
    ".pyc",
    ".pyo",
    ".pyw",
    ".c",
    ".cc",
    ".cxx",
    ".h",
    ".hh",
    ".hpp",
    ".hxx",
    ".m",
    ".mm",
    ".pl",
    ".pm",
    ".pyc",
    ".pyo",
    ".rst",
    ".xhtml",
    ".yml",
    ".epub",
]
audio = [".mp3", ".wav", ".wma", ".aac", ".flac", ".ogg"]
images = [" .bmp", ".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".psd", ".tiff"]
video = [".avi", ".flv", ".mov", ".mp4", ".mpg", ".rm", ".swf", ".wmv"]
files = [
    ".7z",
    ".arj",
    ".bz2",
    ".cab",
    ".gz",
    ".rar",
    ".tar",
    ".tgz",
    ".zip",
    ".deb",
    ".iso",
    ".rpm",
    ".msi",
    ".exe",
    ".AppImage",
    ".flatpakref",
]
vpn = [".ovpn"]
fonts = [" .ttf", ".otf", ".woff", ".woff2"]


dir = input("Enter the directory: ")
path=os.listdir(dir)


def is_audio(file):
    return os.path.splitext(file)[1] in audio


def is_image(file):
    return os.path.splitext(file)[1] in images


def is_video(file):
    return os.path.splitext(file)[1] in video


def is_doc(file):
    return os.path.splitext(file)[1] in docs


def is_file(file):
    return os.path.splitext(file)[1] in files


def is_vpn(file):
    return os.path.splitext(file)[1] in vpn


def is_font(file):
    return os.path.splitext(file)[1] in fonts


for file in path:
    try:
        if is_audio(file):
            shutil.move(file, "/home/zephyr/Music")
            print("Moved " + file + " to Music")

        elif is_image(file):
            shutil.move(file, "/home/zephyr/Pictures")
            print("Moved " + file + " to Pictures")

        elif is_video(file):
            shutil.move(file, "/home/zephyr/Videos")
            print("Moved " + file + " to Videos")

        elif is_doc(file):
            shutil.move(file, "/home/zephyr/Documents")
            print("Moved " + file + " to Documents")

        elif is_file(file):
            shutil.move(file, "/home/zephyr/Programs")
            print("Moved " + file + " to Programs")

    except:
        print(f"{file} Not Moved {FileExistsError}")
        pass
```

Comment: Are you entering an absolute path or relative path at your input prompt?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try using an absolute path. Further help for file systems: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unix-file-system/

Comment: @fireshadow52 Hi, I was using an absolute path, it was working at first but then it didn't work properly

Comment: Well I changed a line of code and it worked smoothly, I changed the lines

`path=os.listdir(dir) 
for file in path ` to the following lines:

`os.chdir(dir)`
`for file in os.listdir() `

Thanks for helping me though